# How to convert a .net ajax project into a control or a component

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am new to component development.
I have designed a file manager using jQuery and ajax with asp.net(seperate project).
I want to make this as a reusable component which should be used across various projects.
Is there any way to make it as a user or custom control..?

Thankz in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not any standard guidelines to make it re-usable but you should try and make it more generic. Example it shouldn't have any domain/user specific code written and then it can be used as custom control.

But in general a custom control project generally have only classes, so if you could share more details about your project, that would be of great help to comment.
For reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa728786(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Design of my application is more generic which can be used in any application. But what my concern is the file manager which i have designed consist of various CSS files and JS Jquery files. to make the filemanager as a reusable one, i want the entire project as a single ascx or a dll. I went through [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163448.aspx) but still i am unable to make it as a single dll or ascx

Comment: Do you have any class files (.cs) in it. If yes then it would become a class library project. or do you have just css and js files?